# Swap with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this

```
<td id="mytd">
    <tr>
        <span>1</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <span>2</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <span>3</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <span>4</span>
    </tr>
</td>
```

I want this change

```
<td id="mytd">
    <tr>
        <span>1</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <span>3</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <span>2</span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <span>4</span>
    </tr>
</td>
```

So, I want to up a span of my election one two or three times position up.
What can I do?
I dont want alphabeticall or asc or desc, I want custom sort and only one span

I have this

```
$('[span="3"]'.closest('tr')).before($('[span="2"]'.closest('tr')));
```

but show me an error

> The object dont accept the property or method 'closest'

Comment: its more of **swap** than **sort**

Comment: a `tr` can't be in a `div`.

Comment: dont worry about tr and div i modify it. swap?

Comment: You want to take a sorted list and "unsort" it?  Randomly?  How do we know which values are to be swapped?  Just moving `3` up a span?  How does it select `3`?   What do you mean by "custom sort"?

Comment: In the edit, you're missing a `)`:  `$('[title="Empresa"]'.closest` `$('[title="Empresa"]').closest`

Comment: In the 2nd edit, you don't have `closest()`, so your error doesn't make sense

Comment: The selector `[span="3"]` won't do what you expect, `[]` mean an attribute, so would be `<span span="3">3</span>` which you don't have.  You could try `$("span:contains(3)")`

Comment: In 5th edit (...) you still have `.closest()` applied to the string, not the jquery object (bracket is in the wrong place).

Comment: i edited. sorry for delay

Comment: @PaoloFrigenti please learn how to ask a question! You edit your question over and over again, changing the whole thing. And your html is even incorrect. Even if you tell, we should not worry about it, it makes it nearly impossible to help. This is **annoying**! Do it right or let it be. Don't waste our time if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move elements using various jquery methods, in this case `insertAfter` looks to solve your issue:

```
$("#mydiv span:eq(2)").insertAfter("#mydiv span:eq(0)")
```

(you may need `insertBefore` to get move it to the first item)

if the element in the first part (`$("#mydiv span:eq(2)")`) already exists, it will be *moved* in the DOM.  If it's new, it will be added, eg:

```
$("<span>9</span>").insertAfter("#mydiv span:eq(0)");
```

will insert a new span, while the first code will move the span.

```js
// 0 based
$("#mydiv span:eq(2)").insertAfter("#mydiv span:eq(0)")
```

```css
span { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** This will need some rework to the selectors given the substantial change to the HTML layout in OPs (various) edits, but the concept remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use anything what can insert element somewhere. Like `insertAfter` for example. You could pick your `span` by the index, with using `:eq()` selector. Then simply place one after another.

```js
$('span:eq(2)').insertAfter('span:eq(0)');
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
```

You could even use `insertBefore`. And this is even the same with another html structure.

```js
$('tr:eq(2)').insertBefore('tr:eq(1)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>1</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>3</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>4</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think this would lead you the way ...